# getchar() into one dimensional array difficulties

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to develop a (simple) personal project which acts as a credit card validator using the classic 'MOD 10' rule.

I am having some difficulty with the first part of my project.

The aim is this:
Take 16 characters, one at a time, from the user.
Each time a character is entered, add it to the corresponding position in the array intInput.
Then later on (not shown), the function validator() is called, with the entire array as a parameter, and it is then validated as appropriate.

The difficulty is that it seems to be 'skip' over i each iteration, going up in iterations of 2, rather than 1. In addition, the values stored in the array appear to be differed to that expected.

```
char intInput[16];
char c;
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    printf("Please insert next char: \n");
    c = getchar();

    printf("\n Character entered:  \n");
    putchar(c);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Value of i is: %d \n", i); // debugging purposes

    intInput[i] = c; // add character input from user, into array for later processung
    printf("ADDED SOMETHING TO INTINPUT, VALUE: %c \n", intInput[i]); // debugging purposes
}
```

Am I using the functions getchar() and putchar() incorrectly?

Comment: Can you post the output ?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing `getchar()` read the `\n` character (which is the carriage return character) when the user press enter to validate the first character. You don't see it, but there is a character here, which make `getchar()` read again and `i` iterate again.

Try printing `c` with printf using an integer like this:

```
  printf("\n Character entered: %d\n", c);
```

It will print the ascii value of the character. Then you can refer to `man ascii` to check what character is really here, even if it is a character not displayed.

I tested with your code, and the problem appears to be really that. Now you have to found a way to bypass or ignore that, have fun :)

Comment: You're correct! I've swapped to using scanf instead of getchar, and compared the ASCII codes I get, and it comes up with NEWLINE. However, I'm not sure where this is coming from, as I have removed all '/n' from my code and this still happens.

Comment: It doesn't come from your code. It comes from the user input. The user press the enter key on his keyboard to validate his input, pressing the enter key sends the `\n` character to the terminal (it is a character like any other in the end). Pressing the enter key is like pressing the 'a' key, except that is sends `\n` (which you canno't see for the sake of reading) instead of 'a'. So what is really going on here is that the user sends two characters instead of one, even if he only want to send one he is forced by the terminal who need a `\n` to validate the input.

Comment: How can I send the previous input without causing it be 'captured' or recognised by the getchar() function?

Comment: What I would do if I were you is use a `while` loop instead of a `for`, that way I could iterate `i` myself at the end of the `while` and I would just use a `if` statement to check if the character I just read is not a `\n`. If it is, then I don't iterate i and I don't put the character inside the `intInput[]`.